# Retrieve number from another number in php

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to retrieve 4119850115 from the below number but i could not extract it properly

```
    <?php
    $num=1000014119850115;
    if(strlen($num)>6){
        $num = substr(($num), 6);
    }
    echo $num;
    ?>
```

the above code gives me 4119850100

but when i assign value to $num as below

```
    $num='1000014119850115';
```

i get 4119850115 which is what i wanted but,
the number is generated dynamically and when i try to add single quotes to it like

```
    $num=1000014119850115;
    $num="'".$num."'";
```

even tried strval() and (string) to convert

its not working it gives 4119850100

can any one help me out with this . was checking this code in codepad.

thanks in advance.

Comment: `1000014119850115` is too large for your system to handle. That's why it doesn't work but does when you make it a string.

Comment: Where are extracting this thing from? A database? A service? What exactly?

Comment: [Necessary documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow) for @JohnConde.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you don't have to put single or double quotes around a number.
If you put quotes PHP considers a string.

Go to see the PHP documentation about the [type juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), I think it will resolve your problem.

Try this and see if it's works :

```
echo (int)$num;
echo (string)$num;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$num = '1000014119850115';

$num = sunstr ($num,6);

$num = intval ($num);
```

Get substring first then convert it to int.